# Posn in scheme/DrRacket

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

> There is a make-posn built into racket by default. Here is an implementation with lambda.

```
(define (my-make-posn x y)
  (lambda (s)
    (cond [(symbol=? s 'x) x]
          [(symbol=? s 'y) y]))
```

But this returns `(lambda (a1) ...)` when I attempt `(my-make-posn 3 2)`.

Why is it like this?

I don't see how lambda is used here?

We type in `(my-make-posn 3 2)` and the function body is:

```
(lambda (s)
  (cond [(symbol=? s 'x) x]
        [(symbol=? s 'y) y]))
```

So what happens to the `(3, 2)`?

Comment: Please don't mangle your question - if you want to add more content or additional questions, go on. If you want to inquire on an answer, do so in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `my-make-posn` wrong; you should be accessing the bound variables by symbol instead:

```
> ((my-make-posn 3 2) 'x)
3
> ((my-make-posn 3 2) 'y)
2
```

The lambda is being used to conditionally return `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of “encoding” of a posn leverages the fact that lambdas are *lexical closures*. This means that lambdas have access to values that are in scope where they are defined, even if they are local bindings. For example, consider this simpler use of a function that returns a lambda:

```
(define (make-adder x)
  (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
```

This is a function that returns a function. The resulting function takes one argument. You can see how it’s used like this:

```
> (define add1 (make-adder 1))
> (add1 1)
2
> (add1 2)
3
> (define add2 (make-adder 2))
> (add2 1)
3
> (add2 2)
4
```

Since functions are just ordinary values, you can also use the resulting function directly, without binding it to a variable name:

```
> ((make-adder 10) 5)
15
```

How does this work? Well, consider the definition of `make-adder`. The inner lambda uses `x`, which is an argument to the `make-adder` function. Since lambdas are closures, this is totally fine, and `x` effectively becomes “locked” to the value provided to `make-adder`; that is, `x` is “closed over” by the inner lambda, hence the name.

For a more concrete example of this, you can imagine evaluating `make-adder` as a sort of substitution:

```
1. (make-adder 1)   ; given

2. ((lambda (x)     ; substitution of the
      (lambda (y)   ; definition of make-adder
        (+ x y)))
    1)

3. (lambda (y)      ; lambda reduction, substituting
     (+ 1 y))       ; 1 for x within the body
```

The same thing is being used for `my-make-posn`. We can do the same sort of expansion for `(my-make-posn 3 2)`:

```
1. (my-make-posn 3 2)                  ; given

2. ((lambda (x y)                      ; substitution of the
      (lambda (s)                      ; definition of my-make-posn
        (cond [(symbol=? s 'x) x]
              [(symbol=? s 'y) y])))
    3 2)

3. (lambda (s)                         ; lambda reduction, substituting
     (cond [(symbol=? s 'x) 3]         ; 3 for x and 2 for y within the body
           [(symbol=? s 'y) 2]))
```

Therefore, the result is a function that takes a symbol, either `'x` or `'y`, and produces one of the two arguments provided to the original `my-make-posn` function.